# How to administrate Server with Apache Guacamole RDG per ssh with TOTP enabled?

Tags: ssh, 22.04

I set up an Apache Guacamole server (v1.4.0) on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The modules guacamole-auth-jdbc-mysql.jar, guacamole-auth-ldap.jar and guacamole-auth-totp.jar are also installed. The openssh-server, tomcat9 and java (openjdk-17) were installed from the apt repositories. All connections to my servers work (RDP, VNC, SSH without TOTP), with the exception of my ssh connections, which are additionally secured via totp (google-authenticator). Is it possible to establish a connection somehow or is there a way to enter a 2FA directly with the password so that only one prompt is necessary (like <password>#<otp>)? I want to explicitly use a one-time password and not an ssh key.

The error message on the target system in the auth.log is as follows:

```
Jan 25 10:19:58 <ssh-server> sshd[271678]: Connection from xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1 port xxxx on xxx.xxx.xxx.xx2 port 22 rdomain ""
Jan 25 10:20:04 <ssh-server> sshd[271678]: Postponed keyboard-interactive for <user> from xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1 port xxxx ssh2 [preauth]
Jan 25 10:20:04 <ssh-server> sshd[271716]: pam_krb5(sshd:auth): user <user> authenticated as <user>@<domain>
Jan 25 10:20:04 <ssh-server> sshd[271678]: Postponed keyboard-interactive/pam for <user> from xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1 port xxxx ssh2 [preauth]
Jan 25 10:20:04 <ssh-server> sshd(pam_google_authenticator)[271716]: Invalid verification code for <user>
Jan 25 10:20:04 <ssh-server> sshd[271678]: error: PAM: Authentication failure for <user> from xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1
Jan 25 10:20:04 <ssh-server> sshd[271678]: Failed keyboard-interactive/pam for <user> from xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1 port xxxx ssh2
Jan 25 10:20:04 <ssh-server> sshd[271678]: Connection closed by authenticating user <user> xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1 port xxxx [preauth]
```

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interested: simply apply the following patch before compiling by simply editing the source code.

[https://github.com/apache/guacamole-server/pull/304/commits](https://github.com/apache/guacamole-server/pull/304/commits/fa5b6e2cb4ea22e912a5b58f3dd0f9d76539e663)

It is for an older version, but also works for the current version 1.4.0.